# Inner product involving the complex conjugate of a function

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

For the inner product space $V=\mathcal{R}([-\pi,\pi];\mathbb{C})$, if the inner product is defined by
$$
\langle f,g\rangle = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\overline{g(x)}dx,
$$
and the $n$-th Fourier coefficient of $f$ is
$$
\hat{f}(n) = \langle f,e^{int}\rangle=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)e^{-int}dt.
$$

Now suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is a $2\pi$-periodic function. My question is, what is the relation between the inner product $\langle f,e^{-int}\rangle$ and $\hat{f}(n)$?

Any of your help will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: If $\hat f(n)=\langle f,e^{int} \rangle=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)e^{-int}\,dt$, then $$\hat f(-n)=\langle f,e^{-int} \rangle=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)e^{int}\,dt==\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(-t)e^{-int}\,dt$$

Comment: And hence $\hat{f}(-n) = \overline{\hat{f}(n)}$?

Comment: No, that is not true unless the imaginary part of $f$ is $0$.